# Funtion App not run defaultazurecredential.gettoken

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, azure-functions-runtime

I have an issue with Function app 1 after step "Start ConfigureServices" it must be run step "defaultazurecredential.gettoken" like Function App 2

[image]
[image]

1. Infrastructure:

+Both of them are located in the same ASP 1.

- Function App 1 located in App Service Plan 1 in App Service Environment 1
- Function App 2 located in App Service Plan 2 in App Service Environment 1

+Both ASP using the same Vnet.

2. Configuration:
   +Both of them use framework 4.8 + Runtime ~4
   [image]

+Both of them use Managed Identity connected to SQL.

2. Code
   Both of them use the same artifact to deploy.
   [image]

The first time I checked Function App 1 ran Framework 6.0 and Function App 2 ran Framework 4.8. I ran the downgrade version Framework "Set-AzWebApp -NetFrameworkVersion v4.8 -Name $App -ResourceGroupName $ResoureGroup" and restart the web app and the issue was still there.

When the issue happened I think Funtion app can't connect to SQL but after investigating and trying many methods it looks like from Funtion App 1 did not run to get token that why it can't authen SQL, not from code, connection string or network.

Does anyone have any idea about this case?

Comment: Do they both have the same config in the portal--and specifically, the same managed identity ID? Are you using a user-assigned managed identity? If so, do both apps have a configuration for AZURE_CLIENT_ID?

Comment: Yeah, both of them have the same config in portal, just have different connection string storage. I have compared between appsetting.json in Kudu but did not see any abnormal, same managed identity, SQL server, Port, Connection string SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

After took many times compared in Kudu I saw the abnormal folder Runtimes in D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin. I deleted the folder and restarted Function App and tried again, it has worked as well.
[image]